# How to make 2 deep copy of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, deep-copy

I am making 2 deep copies of a list. The problem is that first deep copy behaves fine, but second deep copy of the list is being altered based on changes on my original list.

```
import copy

def findThreeLargestNumbers(array):
    # Write your code here.
    org_array2=copy.deepcopy(array)

    org_array1=copy.deepcopy(array)
    
    largest1=0
    largest2=0
    largest3=0
    for i in range(0,len(array)-1):
        if(array[i] >= array[i+1]):
            array[i+1]=array[i]
    largest1=array[-1]
    print(largest1)
    print(array)
    org_array1.remove(largest1)
    
    for i in range(0,len(org_array1)-1):
        if(org_array1[i] >= org_array1[i+1]):
            org_array1[i+1]=org_array1[i]
    largest2=org_array1[-1]
    print(largest2)
    print(org_array1)
    org_array2.remove(largest2)
    
    for i in range(0,len(org_array2)-1):
        if(org_array2[i] >= org_array2[i+1]):
            org_array2[i+1]=org_array2[i]
    largest3=org_array2[-1]
    print(largest3)
    print(org_array2)
array= [10,5,9,10,12,3,517,69,81,74]
findThreeLargestNumbers(array)

517
[10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 517, 517, 517, 517]
81
[10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 69, 81, 81]
517
[10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 517, 517, 517]
```

I want my both the newly copied lists to be independent of each other, as well as independent of original list.

Comment: Why do you think the second copy is being altered based on changes to the original `list`? Looks like it's doing exactly what you asked. You asked to remove the largest value found in `array` from `org_array1` (which it did), then asked to remove the largest value left in `org_array1` from `org_array2` (which means it *doesn't* remove the largest value from `array` unless `array` happened to have the same largest value twice). The code is doing exactly what you asked it to do, and `deepcopy` is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your copies are actually fine.  The issue is that you have only removed the second largest value from org_array2.  So when your logic looks for the largest value, it finds 514 again.  Here's your code with that logic corrected:

```
import copy

def findThreeLargestNumbers(array):
    # Write your code here.
    org_array2=copy.deepcopy(array)

    org_array1=copy.deepcopy(array)
    
    largest1=0
    largest2=0
    largest3=0
    for i in range(0,len(array)-1):
        if(array[i] >= array[i+1]):
            array[i+1]=array[i]
    largest1=array[-1]
    print(largest1)
    print(array)
    org_array1.remove(largest1)
    
    for i in range(0,len(org_array1)-1):
        if(org_array1[i] >= org_array1[i+1]):
            org_array1[i+1]=org_array1[i]
    largest2=org_array1[-1]
    print(largest2)
    print(org_array1)
    org_array2.remove(largest2) # you are removing the 2nd largest only - leaving the largest
    org_array2.remove(largest1) # here you need to remove the largest one as well
    
    for i in range(0,len(org_array2)-1):
        if(org_array2[i] >= org_array2[i+1]):
            org_array2[i+1]=org_array2[i]
    largest3=org_array2[-1]
    print(largest3)
    print(org_array2)
array= [10,5,9,10,12,3,517,69,81,74]
findThreeLargestNumbers(array)
```

Here are the results:

```
$ python findlargest
517
[10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 517, 517, 517, 517]
81
[10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 69, 81, 81]
74
[10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 69, 74]
```

Comment: A (maybe) simpler fix that reduces the repeated work, might be to move the `org_array2=copy.deepcopy(array)` after `org_array1.remove(largest1)` and change it to `org_array2=copy.deepcopy(org_array1)`. This way, you make a copy at the point where the largest value has already been removed (but before you smear the remaining running maximums across `org_array1`), saving the need to remove said largest value again later on. Not even suggesting this for your answer (the modifications you made make the issue clearer to the OP), but might be useful to the OP.

Comment: Of course, the simplest way is to just use sort() and slice off the last three values.  But I would imagine this was assigned by an instructor and there were some parameters that we don't know about guiding it's implementation.  All that said, I agree that your fix is probably better than mine - since the logic flaw I corrected is subtle and your approach just starts from where the previous find ended.  However, the real issue here is that the list is being mutated to find the max value.  Typically, the max value should be left in a variable and set to any larger value found in the loop.

Comment: Ya , it helped. There were few silly mistakes i was doing all while. Thanks for pointing it out  :)

Comment: @Mark: "Typically, the max value should be left in a variable and set to any larger value found in the loop." Of course, in real code, you'd just use the `max` built-in for one element, or `heapq.nlargest` if you need to find `n` largest elements at once, and save a ton of wheel-reinventing (in the case of `heapq.nlargest`, reducing big-O to `O(n log k)` IIRC, where `k` is the number of maximum elements required; if it's not already sorted, the `log k` factor largely disappears; the OP's code is more like `O(kn)`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I agree with you 100%.   I was thinking about programming assignments to get max.  However,  I am so glad you mentioned heap as the way to go in a real life implementation.  I normally would have sorted the array - but you have definitely reminded me of the most efficient way.  I used to attend a class taught by a prof. with the nickname "Dr. Heap", so I should have known better.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to find the largest n values (in this case largest three values), consider sorting list in reverse order and then, extracting the first n non repeating values from the sorted list.

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy
from typing import List

array= [10,5,9,10,12,3,517,69,81,74]

def find_nth_largest(array: 'List', n: int) -> 'List':
    # copy1 = deepcopy(array)
    # Here deepcopy is not necessary since you don't have nested lists shallow copy will  do. 
    copy1 = array[:] # this gets you a copy of one dimensional array. 
    copy1.sort(reverse=True)
    largest_n, count = [copy1[0]], 0
    for item in copy1[1:]:
        if count < n - 1:
            if item != largest_n[-1]:
                largest_n.append(item)
                count += 1
        else:
            return largest_n
    return largest_n

print(find_nth_largest(array, 3))
```

Comment: Very good point - deep copy is not needed here.  And I appreciate the cool slice syntax for making a new copy.

Comment: Once you start using the functions sort or sorted or heapq.nlargest for that matter, you might as well use all of the python tools available to solve the problem (like sets and slices).   But it's good that you shared an algorithm for finding the n largest values (without repeats).   I posted perhaps a minimal solution (although it doesn't answer the original question).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to play with the heapq.largest method suggested by ShadowRanger and I came up with this bit of code (doesn't answer the OC, but it's good to know):

```
import heapq
array= [10,5,517,9,10,81,12,3,517,69,81,74]

# Repeats are not ok
print( sorted(list(set(array)))[-3:] )

# repeats allowed
print( sorted(array)[-3:] )

# repeats not allowed
print(heapq.nlargest( 3, list(set(array)) ) )

# repeats allowed
print(heapq.nlargest( 3, array ) )
```

Here are the results:

```
[74, 81, 517]
[81, 517, 517]
[517, 81, 74]
[517, 517, 81]
```

Fortunately, the results are the same (more or less).   I had to modify the input a little bit to give extra large values.

The `list(set(array))` was used to eliminate "repeats".